# RegisterAssemblyTypes but no PreserveExistingDefaults?

Tags: autofac

When registering types from an assembly using `RegisterAssemblyTypes` I notice that there isn't a `PreserveExistingDefaults` as it is with single type registrations.

I solved this by adding a configuration action to the registration, modifying each registration to preserve defaults:

```
var rb = builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(...);
rb.ActivatorData.ConfigurationActions.Add((t, r) => r.PreserveExistingDefaults());
```

The question is, am I missing some obvious feature already implemented? Or should I commit an appropriate extension method to the project :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it has come up previously - it seems like your extension is on the right track :)